# Split method in java giving exception

Tags: java, string, split

```
package practice;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        String str=(new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);
        String arr[]=str.split("+");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, String's `split` method expects a regex as an argument, and `+` is a reserved character in regex syntax.

If you want to `split` the string by `+` character then you have to `escape` it, e.g.:

```
String arr[] = str.split("\\+");
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)'s javadoc on regex and patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `\\+` because `+` is a special character in regular expressions so you have to escape it :

```
String arr[] = str.split("\\+");
```

Instead of :

```
String arr[] = str.split("+");
```

Comment: str.split("-"); is actually working. In this way "+" should also work.

Comment: mines is not a special character in regex so you can use it like it is not like the + you ca learn more here to find understand what i mean http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/NEWS/regexp.html#info @AkshaySharma

Comment: @AkshaySharma "In this way "+" should also work" what makes you think so? Did you read documentation of `split` method (or duplicate question)? It mentions that `split` is using regex and `+` is one of regex special characters (along with `*`) while `-` is not (at least not in this case). If you want to use it as simple literal you need to escape it.